# Oracle ATG Repository not resolving

Tags: java, oracle, atg, atg-dynamo

I'm newbee with atg. So I'm trying to start existing app at work. And I get this Exception on jboss start.

```
06:54:19,327 INFO  [SQLRepositoryEventServer_production] Service /atg/dynamo/server/SQLRepositoryEventServer_production listening at http://rcovm:33827/
06:54:19,546 INFO  [SQLRepository_production] SQL Repository startup complete
06:54:20,943 INFO  [Promotions_production] Resolving reference to /atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalog_production
06:54:21,047 INFO  [SDSRepository] SQL Repository startup complete
06:54:22,881 WARN  [DistributorSender] No remote servers configured
06:54:23,326 INFO  [VersionManagerRepository] SQL Repository startup complete
06:54:23,391 INFO  [SQLRepositoryEventServer] Service /atg/dynamo/server/SQLRepositoryEventServer listening at http://rcovm:58588/
06:54:23,449 INFO  [VanityUriRepository-ver] SQL Repository startup complete
06:54:23,478 INFO  [VanityUriRepository] SQL Repository startup complete
06:54:23,551 INFO  [SEORepository-ver] SQL Repository startup complete
06:54:23,577 INFO  [SEORepository] SQL Repository startup complete
06:54:24,025 ERROR [nucleusNamespace.] Unable to resolve component /atg/commerce/catalog/ProductCatalog 
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at atg.adapter.gsa.GSAItemDescriptor.<init>(GSAItemDescriptor.java:231)
        at atg.adapter.gsa.xml.TemplateParser.createItemDescriptor(TemplateParser.java:811)
        at atg.adapter.gsa.xml.TemplateParser.addDocumentToTemplate(TemplateParser.java:658)
        at atg.adapter.gsa.xml.TemplateParser.addToTemplate(TemplateParser.java:530)
        at atg.adapter.gsa.xml.TemplateParser.addToTemplate(TemplateParser.java:422)
        at atg.adapter.gsa.GSARepository.parseFirstPass(GSARepository.java:6818)
        at atg.adapter.gsa.GSARepository.getItemDescriptor(GSARepository.java:2968)
```

My atg module list is:

```
    atg.dynamo.modules=DCS,DCS.AbandonedOrderServices,DCS.CustomCatalogs.Versioned,DCS.PublishingAgent,DCS-UI.Versioned,PubPortlet,B2CCommerce.Versioned,DCS-CSR.Management,SiteAdmin.Versioned,DAF.Search.Routing,DPS.Search.Index,D
CS.Search.Order.Index,DAF.Search.Index,MYAPP.MYAPPAdmin,MYAPP.Integration.TeamApproach,MYAPP.MYAPPMobileCore,MYAPP.RCBCore,MYAPP.MYAPPMobileWebApp,MYAPP.RCBWebApp,MYAPP.MYAPPSSOWebApp,MYAPP.MYAPPUserprofileApp,MYAPP.MYAPPCore,MYAPP.MYAPPPub,MYAPP.MYAPPPubAdmin,MYAPP.MYAPP
WebApp,MYAPP.Integration.Cybersource,MYAPP.Integration.Amazon,MYAPP.Integration.GSASearch,MYAPP.MYAPPSabaWS,MYAPP.AuxModule,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Dev,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Stage,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Prod,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Dev.commerce,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Dev.CSC,MYAPP.env
.Oracle-Dev.publishing,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Dev.index,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Stage.commerce,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Stage.CSC,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Stage.publishing,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Stage.index,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Prod.commerce,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Prod.CSC,MYAPP.env.Oracle-
Prod.publishing,MYAPP.env.Oracle-Prod.index,MYAPP.env.Oracle-DR,MYAPP.env.Oracle-DR.commerce,MYAPP.env.Oracle-DR.CSC,MYAPP.env.Oracle-DR.publishing,MYAPP.env.Oracle-DR.index,MYAPP.env.Oracle-PreProd,MYAPP.env.Oracle-PreProd.commerce,MYAPP.env.Oracl
e-PreProd.CSC,MYAPP.env.Oracle-PreProd.publishing,MYAPP.env.Oracle-PreProd.index,DafEar
```

Enviroment:
Java 6,
Jboss 5.0.1,
ATG10.0.3,
Oracle RedHat

I can provide more information, ask please. I don't know what info will be useful.

Comment: Which environment are you trying to build? Looks like you've got everything in this build including your Storefront, Staging, BCC, and CSC modules. Somewhere in all this your `ProductCatalog` isn't loading correctly. Are there no `DataSource` errors?

Comment: can you please check your CustomCatalog.xml there may be some errors